# How to display std::string into CEdit in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, cedit

I have a MFC project written in C++ and I want to display some text in a CEdit control.
So far, I tried this:

MFCApplication1Dlg.h

```
...

private:
    static CEdit m_progress;
public:
    static void setProgress(std::string message);

...
```

MFCApplication1Dlg.cpp

```
...

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::setProgress(std::string message)
{
    m_progress.SetWindowTextW((LPCTSTR)message.c_str());
}

void logMessage(std::string message)
{
    if(logFile.is_open())
    {
        logFile << message;
        logFile.flush();
        CMFCApplication1Dlg::setProgress(message);

    }
}

...
```

When I compile I have this error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class CEdit CMFCApplication1Dlg::m_progress" (?m_progress@CMFCApplication1Dlg@@0VCEdit@@A)
```

Can anyone tell me what is with this error and how could I display the messages in that CEdit?

Comment: There are tons of duplicates to this question, and it has to do with you only *declaring* the static member variably, and not *defining* in anywhere. I.e. has nothing to do with `std::string` and the setting  of the member variables value. Please do a quick search for *c++ static member variables definition*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the static member in your cpp file:

```
CEdit CMFCApplication1Dlg::m_progress;
```

In the header it is just declared, not defined.

Also, I would expect `SetWindowTextW` to take a `wstring::c_str()` parameter, and not a `string::c_str()`.

Comment: That was it. And you we're right, `SetWindowTextW` has to take a `wstring::c_str()` parameter. Thanks a lot. Also I need to set my messages one after another in that CEdit, but with the code I wrote, it just overwrites the messages, displaying only the last message. Any ideas?